# What factors does an admissions commitee use when considering a non-degree candidate in grad school?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, engineering

I have an interest in taking some very specific engineering classes at my local (very competitive) university. I already have an MSEE. As it is not close enough to my current career path, I am trying to get a better background in some areas and stay up-to-date in others. Since I don't really want a PhD, I had applied as a self-financed non-degree candidate. But, I was not accepted.

I'm wondering, is any consideration given to degree status during admissions? Is the admissions process typically identical to MS and PhD candidates?

Answer (score 2):

Not typically identical to MS or PhD but some level of relevant competency is expected of you before admission can be given in that field

Comment: Hello, Jeremy. Welcome to Academia.SE. Your answer is in need of some improvement. Please try to include some more details in your answer so that it will be of benefit to other users. Thanks.